# Bootstrap nested layout (2 columns in one column)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to layout a grid in bootstrap that consists on the desktop of a full 12 column layout, inside that, there is a 8 column grid and a 4 column grid. the 8 column grid is filled with an image/text, the 4 column grid consists in its own of 2 elements below each other containting image/text.

on smaller breakpoint the layout should simply show 3 elements in same size below each other.

I fiddled around but I do not get it to work. Below you also find next to the html a sketch from what I am trying to achieve. Any hints? I do not feel this is possible out of the box with bootstrap 4.

```
    <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui illo eaque libero, modi
                            porro iusto magni sint laboriosam eius. Fugiat non ad pariatur sit libero optio
                            doloremque molestiae harum! Rem!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
                                ratione blanditiis tempore tempora non. Neque adipisci maxime aspernatur voluptate
                                sunt non totam, temporibus provident necessitatibus distinctio impedit nobis aut at!
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo
                                ratione blanditiis tempore tempora non. Neque adipisci maxime aspernatur voluptate
                                sunt non totam, temporibus provident necessitatibus distinctio impedit nobis aut at!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui illo eaque libero, modi
                            porro iusto magni sint laboriosam eius. Fugiat non ad pariatur sit libero optio
                            doloremque molestiae harum! Rem!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

As a sketch it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the smaller col width. You also had an extra unnecessary row and col wrapping it.  Below is a working example of what you are looking for. `col-12` class was added for any screen smaller than md

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui illo eaque libero, modi porro iusto magni sint laboriosam eius. Fugiat non ad pariatur sit libero optio doloremque molestiae harum! Rem!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ratione blanditiis tempore tempora non. Neque adipisci maxime aspernatur voluptate sunt non totam, temporibus provident necessitatibus distinctio impedit nobis aut at!
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ratione blanditiis tempore tempora non. Neque adipisci maxime aspernatur voluptate sunt non totam, temporibus provident necessitatibus distinctio impedit nobis aut at!
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui illo eaque libero, modi porro iusto magni sint laboriosam eius. Fugiat non ad pariatur sit libero optio doloremque molestiae harum! Rem!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet.

```css
.row {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.col .card {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.card{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x150" alt="Image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x150" alt="Image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>Some text Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x150" alt="Image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>Some text Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```